# Php MySQL changing limit by select box selection

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently facing a problem displaying results by a limit, my query ends in `ORDER BY date DESC limit $limit` and my html code is

```
<select name="limit" id="limit">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

In my PHP I have `$limit=$_POST["limit"];`

Now, this is basically working, except that on page load the form containing `limit` isn't posted, so I get a query error until I change the value of limit and submit it.

How can I have a default value selected on initial page load?

Comment: can you show your select query?

Comment: <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option> Is this you are looking for?

Comment: set **$limit=0** before the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `$limit` to a default value like 0 and change it only if there's a posted value:

```
$limit = 0;
if(isset($_POST["limit"])) $limit = $_POST["limit"];
```

Also note that you shouldn't paste user input in queries since this could lead to [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'll accept as correct answer in a few minutes when it lets me.

Comment: Is it possible to have the selection saved on form submission?

Comment: If the post is submitted you have the value in the post global and then you can do what you want with it, I'm not sure what you mean by save the selection.

Comment: I'd recommend you use `filter_var()` or `filter_input()` as a habit when passing data and accessing via `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the variable is empty then set it to a default value.

```
$limit = $_POST["limit"];
if ($limit == '') $limit = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this you are looking for

On page load selected="selected" takes default value.

```
<option value="15" selected="selected">15</option>
```

In PHP

```
 if(isset($_POST['limit']) && !empty($_POST['limit'])) {
  $limit = $_POST['limit']; 
 } else {
  $limit = '5'; /* Your default value*/
 }
```

In Query, try something like this

```
ORDER BY date DESC limit ".$limit;
```

Comment: Not very cool to not check what is passed from the form (you can edit it easily before submitting), especially if you're not using prepared statements.

Comment: what you are saying? I dont get u

Comment: what if I save the webpage and edit it - e.g. `<option value="15; 'nefarious SQL statement here" selected="selected">15</option>` - what you are suggesting is not generally accepted as good practice.

Comment: Nope, why am suggsting If <option value="">--SELECT LIMIT--</select> In this case the post will send empty value. So I asked to use selected='selected' for make default value.

Comment: You should read about prepared statements and why you should use them. As it is, I could pass `'15; DROP DATABASE myDatabase'` or whatever I want and execute a second SQL statement. We're not only interested in whether `$limit` is `NULL`, but whether it contains a valid input. `filter_var()` could help... What you suggest may work, but it's not exactly very secure.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the conditional check in PHP

like this

```
$limit=isset($_POST["limit"])?$_POST["limit"]:5; // or change the value which you want to show onload
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['limit']` will not exist until `limit` is posted e.g. by form submission.

If you want a default, I suggest:

```
$limit = filter_var($_POST['limit'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if(empty($limit) || !$limit) $limit = 10;
```

Then bind $limit to your prepared statement - assuming that's what you're using.

If you're not using prepared statements then you'd better check the content of `$_POST['limit']` before concatenating it into a SQL statement like other posts here are suggesting.